# border-box of input not working as expected

Tags: html, css

When I set border-box to input without a specific height and width, padding increases the width of the input.
On the other hand, if I do the same, but with a established size, then it works as normal as on a regular div, setting the padding without changing the width of the input.

**Short snippet**

```css
#input1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#input2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  input1: <input type="text" name="text" id="input1"> <br/><br/>
  input2: <input type="text" name="text" id="input2">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing):

> Note: In contrast to the length and percentage values, **the auto value of the width and height properties** (as well as other keyword values introduced by later specifications, unless otherwise specified) **is not influenced by the box-sizing property**, and always sets the size of the content box.

In your first example you didn't set any width so it's `auto` and `box-sizing` with do nothing (`content-box` will behave the same way as `border-box`). Padding and borders will logically increase the overall size.